# How to embed a GeoTools map in a existing java swing application

Tags: java, swing, geotools

I have a java GUI swing application with three frames. I want to load a map from a shape file and draw the map on an existing application frame. For this I use GeoTools framework. I've looked at the examples and all examples have drawn the map on a separate GUI window `JMapFrame`.

(I've followed [this](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/netbeans.html) link )

Is there a way which we can embed a map that we have created using Geotools to an existing Java Swing application.

Comment: Maybe start by taking a look at [MapPane](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/swing/JMapPane.html)

Comment: A quick look at the Javadocs suggests maybe embedding a JMapPane in the existing frame may be the way to go. I have not tried it however.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently working on what you suggested. In the mean time, my end application would need features like adding new lines, nodes to the map, selecting a line/node on the map and displaying properties of that selected part and drawing names/values on the map. (Eg: population of a city). I'm curious whether JMapPane is the answer for this as the document says JMapPane is just for demo purpose, but not intended for Desktop GIS apps. Please comment on this.